# Android NumberPicker Incorrectly Handling Touches

Tags: android, numberpicker

I have created a `NumberPicker` inside of a relative layout with the following code.

```
<NumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/numberPicker"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="92dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />
```

In my Fragment I am configuring the `NumberPicker` with this code:

```
    final NumberPicker np = (NumberPicker) dialog.findViewById(R.id.numberPicker);
    np.setMaxValue(10);
    np.setMinValue(0);
    np.setValue(0);
    np.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);
    np.setDescendantFocusability(NumberPicker.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
```

This is causing a ton of odd behavior on the NumberPicker and I'm trying to determine if I have somehow caused this or if this is a bug.

This behavior is occurring in Android 4 and Android 5 using a Nexus 7, HTC One and Panasonic Toughpad.

1. Sometimes the arrows above and below the Number Picker do not appear. When they do, they only work if the number picker is not at its min/max value. If it is at its min/max the arrow will cause the number to jump visually, and then return to its value. In some cases one arrow will appear and the other one will be absent.
2. When the number picker is at its min/max value tapping and dragging does not cause the value to increment/decrement. Instead the number jumps in place being pulled by my touch and then instantly moving back into place. To fix this you need to drag in the opposite direction and then continue your motion.
3. The selected number is not always aligned in the center of the `NumberPicker` when it is small enough. This causes either the top or bottom of the number to be culled. As soon as you start scrolling the number returns to its position.

Comment: I pasted your code into an activity with an AppCompat theme.  I've forgotten how the widget is styled on other themes.  With AppCompat, there are no up/down arrows.  I don't see the odd behavior you describe on devices running KitKit and Lollipop.  What theme are you using?

Comment: Thanks for testing it, I am using a custom theme based off of Holo.Light. The issue appears to be related to the height of the `NumberPicker`. As it gets shorter more issues appear and more prominently. I was able to get around the issues by increasing the size of the picker, but it's not an elegant solution.

Comment: A further note: the arrows appear to only display on my Toughpad. I guess that's just another quirk of Android. The HTC One and Nexus don't have arrows.